Laravel session Is not working (Laravel + firestore) on google cloud run
I am facing session issue in laravel firestore project which is deployed on google cloud run. Locally, everything works fine, but it doesn't even running on Google cloud.
This is my middleware
class FirestoreAuth {
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Closure(\Illuminate\Http\Request): (\Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response)  $next
     */
    public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next) {
        // Check if the 'user' session variable exists
        if (!$request->session()->has('user')) {
            session()->forget('user');
            return redirect()->route('login'); // Redirect to login if not available
        }

        return $next($request); // Proceed to the next request
    }
}


And User Controller login function 
function login(Request $request){
$request->validate([
        'email' => 'required|string|email',
        'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
      ]);
      // Retrieve user from Firestore
      $userCollection = $this->firestore->collection('users');
      $query = $userCollection->where('deleted_at', '=', null)->where('email', '=', $request->email)->limit(1);
      $userDocuments = $query->documents();
      if ($userDocuments->isEmpty()) {
        return redirect()->back()->withErrors(['email' => 'User not found.']);
      }

      $user = $userDocuments->rows()[0];
      // Verify password
      // dd($user->data()['password']);

      if (Hash::check($request->password, $user->data()['password'])) {
        // Create a session or token for the user
        // You might want to use Laravel's built-in authentication or a custom session mechanism
        // Here is a simple example of setting session data
        $request->session()->put(['user' => $user->data(),'id' => $user->id()]); // Store user data in session
        return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Login successful!');
      }
}

The issue is that whenever I try to login, I'm redirected back to login on google cloud run. I have put the correct credentials, but I still get redirected to login because the session has no user key. Maybe the session doesn't work on google cloud run.
session(['user' => $user->data(),'id' => $user->id()]); I also tried this way

note: I'm also facing the error 419 page expired, but I removed verifycsrftoken login route.

Your question doesn't represent a minimal repro making it more difficult for us to help you and likely that your question will be down-voted. I suspect the more likely issue is that your Cloud Run service is unable to access Firestore to acquire the user's credentials, incorrectly acquiring the password from the Firestore document, and/or incorrectly verifying the hashes. If any of these steps fail, the session will not be created correctly and the process will loop (redirecting to login). Minimally please add debugging steps proving the flow through login.

The problem seems to be that Google Cloud Run doesn't support per-session files, as the service is stateless by default. Solutions include:
Switch to Redis or Firestore for Sessions: Set SESSION_DRIVER=redis (or another central store)
in .env. Redis can be configured with Google's Memorystore, or Firestore can be used with custom setups.
SESSION_DRIVER=redis
REDIS_HOST=your-redis-host
REDIS_PASSWORD=your-redis-password
REDIS_PORT=6379

Set SESSION_DRIVER=cookie: If Redis is not in place, use Cookie Sessions: store session data in encrypted cookies-should be good enough for smaller data.
Set Secure Configs: Insure SESSION_DOMAIN and SESSION_SECURE_COOKIE=true in .env if using a custom domain and HTTPS.
Check CSRF: Ensure your forms include @csrf even if CSRF is disabled on certain routes.
Flush the config and cache after modification
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan cache:clear


Can u let me know  how i can do this firestore becuase i have created sessions collection  in fireste and handle firestoresession  session  stored succesfully but when i try to get this in middleware its not get

Try to register your FirestoreSessionHandler in AppServiceProvider so Laravel may use to store sessions.
Middleware : Get Session Check the session is accessed correctly in middleware
public function handle(Request $request, Closure $next)
{
if (!$request->session()->has('user')) {
return redirect()->route('login');
}
return $next($request);
}
and then
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear

Currently i am using firestore session in   FirestoreServiceProvider  public function boot(): void {
//
Session::extend('firestore', function ($app) {
return new FirestoreSessionHandler($app->make(FirestoreClient::class));
});
}  so i need to change it from FirestoreServiceProvider to AppServiceProvider?


Yes, try moving your FirestoreSessionHandler registration to AppServiceProvider. This ensures Laravel recognizes Firestore as the session handler globally, which might resolve your middleware access issue.
public function boot(): void {     Session::extend('firestore', function ($app) {         return new FirestoreSessionHandler($app->make(FirestoreClient::class));     }); } 
like this

ok i change but <?php
return [
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider::class,
App\Providers\FirestoreServiceProvider::class,
];
this is boostrap/provider.php file in laravel 11 i have register here may be its not issue what u think?

Yes, but the key point is that you should make sure the FirestoreSessionHandler is being registered in the AppServiceProvider so Laravel can properly handle the session across the entire application, including middleware. make sure to set .env SESSION_DRIVER=firestore

the issue is that when i try to login and store session $request->session()->put(['user' => $user->data(),'id' => $user->id()]);  then after this line seesion('user') its getting but while redirect any other url then friestore generate new doc id in session that why i am not able to authenticate can u let me know any best way to handle this
